# FileZilla won't download *cshtml

Tags: ftp, filezilla

When I try to download my website with FileZilla, some files won't download.

Example:

```
Views/Home/Dashboard.cshtml 
11:52:52 Status: Transferring files ignored 
11:52:52 Response: 250 CWD command successful.
```

I need to make a full backup.

No filter active.

The "piece" of log:

```
23/10/2014 11:40:54 11 5232 Status: Skipping the transfer of /www.solicitemeusite.com.br/cartao-vale-alimentacao-meusite/GerarPdf/PropostaComercialmeusite[0][20141010][4971].pdf 
23/10/2014 11:40:54 5232 State 11: Transfer files ignored 
23/10/2014 11:40:54 11 5232 Status: Starting transfer /www.solicitemeusite.com.br/cartao-vale-alimentacao-meusite/GerarPdf/PropostaComercialmeusite[0][20141010][3889].pdf 
23/10/2014 11:40:54 11 5232 Status: Skipping the transfer of /www.solicitemeusite.com.br/cartao-vale-alimentacao-meusite/GerarPdf/PropostaComercialmeusite[0][20141010][3889].pdf 
23/10/2014 11:40:54 5232 State 11: Transfer files ignored 
23/10/2014 11:40:54 11 5232 Status: Starting transfer /www.solicitemeusite.com.br/cartao-vale-alimentacao-meusite/GerarPdf/PropostaComercialmeusite[0][20141010][2267].pdf 
23/10/2014 11:40:54 11 5232 Status: Skipping the transfer of /www.solicitemeusite.com.br/cartao-vale-alimentacao-meusite/GerarPdf/PropostaComercialmeusite[0][20141010][2267].pdf 
23/10/2014 11:40:54 5232 State 11: Transfer files ignored 
23/10/2014 11:40:54 11 5232 Status: Starting transfer /www.solicitemeusite.com.br/cartao-vale-alimentacao-meusite/GerarPdf/PropostaComercialmeusite[0][20141010][2211].pdf 
23/10/2014 11:40:54 11 5232 Status: Skipping the transfer of /www.solicitemeusite.com.br/cartao-vale-alimentacao-meusite/GerarPdf/PropostaComercialmeusite[0][20141010][2211].pdf 
23/10/2014 11:40:54 5232 State 11: Transfer files ignored 
23/10/2014 11:40:54 11 5232 Status: Starting transfer /www.solicitemeusite.com.br/cartao-vale-alimentacao-meusite/GerarPdf/PropostaComercialmeusite[0][20141010][2077].pdf 
23/10/2014 11:40:54 11 5232 Status: Skipping the transfer of /www.solicitemeusite.com.br/cartao-vale-alimentacao-meusite/GerarPdf/PropostaComercialmeusite[0][20141010][2077].pdf 
23/10/2014 11:40:54 5232 State 11: Transfer files ignored 
23/10/2014 11:40:54 11 5232 Status: Starting transfer /www.solicitemeusite.com.br/cartao-valley-food-meusite/Images/meusite-logo.gif 
23/10/2014 11:40:54 5232 11 Command: CWD /www.solicitemeusite.com.br/cartao-valley-food-meusite/Images 
23/10/2014 11:40:54 5232 State 3: Transfer successful file transfer 20.4 KiB in 1 second 
23/10/2014 11:40:54 5232 1 Response: 250 CWD command successful. 
23/10/2014 11:40:54 5232 1 Command: PWD 
23/10/2014 11:40:54 8 5232 Response: 200 PORT command successful. 
23/10/2014 11:40:54 5232 8 Command: RETR PropostaComercialmeusite [0] [20,141,021] [129] pdf 
23/10/2014 11:40:54 12 5232 Response: 200 PORT command successful. 
23/10/2014 11:40:54 5232 12 Command: RETR PropostaComercialmeusite [0] [20,141,021] [1296] pdf 
23/10/2014 11:40:54 7 5232 Response: 226 Transfer complete. 
23/10/2014 11:40:54 5 5232 Response: 226 Transfer complete. 
... 
... 
... 
23/10/2014 15:02:36 5232 3 Status: Starting transfer /simulador.brasil-meusite.com.br/Scripts/Deletar/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/ui/minified/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-nl.min.js 
23/10/2014 15:02:36 5232 3 State: Leaping transfer /simulador.brasil-meusite.com.br/Scripts/Deletar/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/ui/minified/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-nl.min.js 
23/10/2014 15:02:36 5232 State 3: Transfer files ignored
```

Comment: Any [Filters](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Filename_Filters) setup in FileZilla?

Comment: Can you share larger piece of the log?

Comment: Is this an actual log or did you translate it from another language? Because there are no such messages in FileZilla. If it is translation, it might be better if you switch FileZilla to English and post an English log. Also include the log into a question the next time (you can edit the question), do not post it as an "answer".

Comment: Are you still working on this issue?